# Laravel 5.0 get the id of the row inserted in a pivot table after attach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a newsletter and block model that has a many to many relation. When I attach a block to a newsletter I want the id of the row that was insterted in the pivot table.

This is what I tried but results in "null"

```
$newsletter = Newsletter::findOrFail($newsletterId);
$newsletterBlock = $newsletter->blocks()->attach($blockId);
dd($newsletterBlock);
```

Comment: Usually, a pivot table does not have a dedicated primary key but rather a composite key consisting of the primary column of each table.

Comment: i have id, block_id, newsletter_id in my pivot table

Comment: And why do you need an extra primary key?

Comment: That's how it works in laravel

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is old, however nobody gave the right answer. If you are in a situation that your pivot table has a primary key.
Using `withPivot` method is useful when you want get the id when you load the related model. However when you attach something you can not get the pivot_id;
In these situations best thing to do is to use a model that is connected to the pivot table, then only thing you need to do is inserting into pivot table using its model instead of attaching two models together.

in this example, first create a model called `BlockNewsLetter` if it is necessary fill the `$table` and `$fillable` attributes of the model and then you are good to go.

```
$newsletter = Newsletter::findOrFail($newsletterId);
$blockNewsLetterPivot = BlockNewsLetter::updateOrCreate([
       'block_id' => $block_id ,
       'newsLetter_id' => $newsletter->id
    ]);
$inserted_pivot_id = $blockNewsLetterPivot->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, haven't test it but this should work:

```
/** Newsletter.php */
public function blocks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Block')
            ->withPivot('id');
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$newsletter = Newsletter::findOrFail($newsletterId);
$newsletter->blocks()->attach($blockId);

// then you could:
foreach($newsletter->blocks as $block)
{
    dd($block->pivot->id);
}
```

---

Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) of the docs.

Comment: Why should I loop over the blocks? I just want the new record that was created so the last one.

Comment: @Michael it was just an example. The thing is you could access the pivot data with the syntax: `$id = $block->pivot->id;`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how I can get the id of that new row that was inserted in the pivot table. I cant do $block->pivot->id because there might me multiple same block_id's

Comment: That's why I put the `foreach()`, this is because this is a many to many relationship: each `Newsletter` have many `Block`.. for each Block attached you can access the pivot data stored in the intermediate table.

Comment: So how do I loop over the blocks and just get the last one?

Comment: Can't I create a model for my pivot table or something?

Comment: You don't need to loop over the results. The relationship returns an instance of the Collection class, so you could call the `last()` method: `$last_block = $newsletter->blocks->last();`. Check the [API](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L1093)

Comment: I think in that version of Laravel you cannot. But in the next versions it is [available](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models). I suggest you to upgrade your Laravel version to at least the latest LTS (5.5).

Comment: it doesn't work with last() i just did it like this DB::table('block_newsletter')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

Comment: I don't think you understand, I don't need to fetch a block i need to fetch something from the pivot table

Comment: Dude, to access the intermediate data on the pivot table you ened to access the block. Laravel will add the pivot data defined in the relationship (check the `->withPivot(...)` in an attribute called `pivot`. That's why I could do: `$block->pivot->id`.

Comment: Yeah when I do that I always get result 13 while I have more than 20 records

Comment: That might be linked with another issue. The thing is that you get to your desired attribute.. could you managed to access to that field?